# \cite inside bib file

Tags: biber

I am using a `\cite` inside a bib file (ref to an article in a journal but I add: see same paper in 'collected work')
Eg:

```
@article{volterra_1887_4,
author = {Volterra, Vito},
title = {Sopra le funzioni che dipendono da altre funzioni. Nota II.},
journaltitle = {Rendiconti della Reale Accademia dei Lincei},
year = {1887},
series = {4},
volume = {III},
pages = {141-146},
**note = {cf. {\OE}uvres \cite[p.303]{volterra_oeuvre_1}}**,
}
```

My problem is that it requires 4 passes of LaTeX to give the right reference (biber). And when I add `\refsection` in main document, those embedded ref do no longer appear.

Comment: Can you add a MWE? A full example would help us, there are also other Biber features that might help you here (`related`).